# Removing background when generating a ggplot with shared legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to generate a `ggplot` which shares the legend from a list of `ggplots`.

Here's my code:

```
#generate the list of plots:
set.seed(1)
plot.list <- vector(mode="list",2)
plot.list[[1]] <- ggplot(data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:3],10),val=rnorm(30)),aes(val,color=group))+geom_density(adjust=1)+theme_minimal()
set.seed(10)
plot.list[[2]] <- ggplot(data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:3],10),val=rnorm(30)),aes(val,color=group))+geom_density(adjust=1)+theme_minimal()
```

So:

```
plot.list[[1]]
```

[image]

and,

```
plot.list[[2]]
```

[image]

Now, to make a single plot that shares their legend:

```
g <- ggplotGrob(plot.list[[1]]+theme_minimal()+theme(legend.position="right"))$grobs
legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
plot(legend)
lheight <- sum(legend$height)
lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
gl <- lapply(plot.list,function(x) x+theme_minimal()+theme(legend.position="none"))
gl <- c(gl,nrow=1,ncol=2)

combined <- switch(position,"bottom"=arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob,gl),
                                                 legend,
                                                 ncol=1,
                                                 heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight)),
                   "right" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob,gl),
                                         legend,
                                         ncol=2,
                                         widths=unit.c(unit(1,"npc")-lwidth,lwidth)))
```

But that (`plot(combined)`) generates a plot with the gray background:

[image]

How can I get the `combined` plot have the same background as the individual plots?

Comment: `plot()` is not the right function. Try grid.draw

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would be better off combining the data frames and using `facet_wrap()`?

```
set.seed(1)
df1<-data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:3],10),val=rnorm(30),dfz=1)

set.seed(10)
df2<-data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:3],10),val=rnorm(30),dfz=2)

df<-rbind(df1,df2)#combine dataframes 

ggplot(df,aes(val,color=group))+geom_density(adjust=1)+theme_minimal()+
  facet_wrap(~dfz,scales='free') #facet_wrap by distinguishing column
```

[image]

Comment: @dan was this answer useful? I can't reproduce your code. I get `Error: object 'position' not found`.